# I can't use blogger preview anything

Tags: blogger

My blog address is www.dianbanjiu.com. When I need to preview a post or theme, the URL redirects to `508567853743127661_30kg36ta82bdddas2a5a8123123xff409fas70.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=APq4FmBXlGGVCqMPWOX6Mts-yRTlbKZey1iEp8pXXP3jqh-o-4f8zAaCvo8gBwMdjCZZcBj` - preview fails.

But preview works if I replace it with `www.dianbanjiu.com/b/...`

What caused this situation? How can I solve it?